# How to host a WCF Service with entity framework having operations that have more than two parameters

Tags: wcf

I am new in WCF and started learning.I want to host a WCF service for android app but I don't know how to invoke a method and what is the uritemplate.

*the IService is:*

```
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UserReg", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

    public string UserReg(string user_id, string first_name, string last_name, string email, string password);
}
```

*and the Service is:*

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{ 
    P_M_SEntities objEntities = new P_M_SEntities();

    public string UserReg(string user_id, string first_name, string last_name, string email, string password)
    {
        User_Registration tblObj = new User_Registration();
        tblObj.user_id = Convert.ToInt32(user_id);
        tblObj.first_name = first_name;
        tblObj.last_name = last_name;
        tblObj.email = email;
        tblObj.password = EncryptPwd(password);
        objEntities.User_Registration.Add(tblObj);

        objEntities.SaveChanges();
        string objstring = tblObj.user_id.ToString();
        return string.Format(objstring);    
     }
}
```

I'm not familiar with WCF so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You're doing a Rest service , what's not working for you exactly , your question lacks details